# is better to call a inBuilt VBA function with or without its Class?

Tags: performance, vba

Some inBuilt functions in Vba can be called with or without its class.  Which one is better to use?

When calling a Sub/Function

```
vba.Format(date,"yy-MM-dd")
'or
Format(date,"yy-MM-dd")
```

Also when dimensioning a variable, the class might or might not be used.  In this case, which would be better?

```
Dim xmlDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
'or
Dim xmlDoc As DOMDocument60
```

I tend to use the class and name just in case someone has defined a function/Sub/type that could bring conflicts.  But how about performance?  When having a great amount of codes and procedures, could one or the other have an impact on performance/speed?
Is there any other aspect to take in account when deciding whether to use one form or the other?

Answer (score 5):

If I am understanding you correctly, and if my understanding of VBA is correct, then it doesn't make much difference in terms of performance whether you qualify the property or method with the library prefix. I don't think it is necessary to qualify the objects referenced within the vba library (If you are indeed working in a vba environment, as opposed to say .net using interop), but when you set external references (such as MSXML2, or Scripting), it might be beneficial to fully qualify the function reference for clarity.

Using the fully qualified name can improve clarity (in some cases). A year down the road, when someone else goes to maintain your code, it can be helful for them to recognize that certain functions are defined in a referenced library (such as MSXML2). Also, in cases where the referenced library contains a function with the same name as either the vba library, or another library set as a reference, you will need to qualify the function name.

Fully qualifying function names from referenced libraries is probably good practice. While the vba library is ALSO set as a reference from within a vba application, my take would be that is the one library you DON'T need to qualify.

Note that using fully qualified names DOES mean some extra typing. Since you app is written in vba, using vba.Function would be semi-redundant. But for referenced libraries, you need to choose between clarity/maintainability, and ease of typing (I have subscribed to the school that says "write the code in a way that will benefit the next person who has to deal with it" before making it "easier" for myself to write.

Comment: This mirrors my practice almost exactly--don't bother with quaiifying `vba.FuncName`, but do it for referenced libraries. This is especially important in any app that include references to both DAO and ADO, since they contain very different objects with the same names.

Comment: +1, the only reason to use the FQN for a member of the VBA standard library is if there is an ambiguity between names. For example if you have a custom collection class which exposes a `Join` method then you might do `Join = VBA.Join( ... )` - but for general usage, using the FQN is not required and negatively impacts readability (IMO)